# How to make a DIV appear after a set amount of time and after the user has scrolled past a certain point

Tags: jquery, time, scroll, delay

I've got a special DIV content box after each of my blogposts in wordpress.

I'd love to find a way to make it only appear after the user has scrolled down past the blog post, and after a set time delay of 1 second.

Is there any way to do that with javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below.  You can test it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPrmd/28/)

```
  $("#div1").hide();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
//alert(windowHeight);
var divHeight = $("#div0").height();
//var alert(divHeight);
var divBottomPos = $("#div0").offset().top + divHeight; //alert(divBottomPos);

var divIsShowing = false;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    var bottomPageScrollPos = scrollPos + windowHeight;
    //alert(bottomPageScrollPos);
    if ((bottomPageScrollPos > divBottomPos) && (!divIsShowing)) {
        $("#div1").delay(1000).show(0);
        divIsShowing = true;
    } else if ((bottomPageScrollPos < divBottomPos) && (divIsShowing)) {
        $("#div1").hide();
        divIsShowing = false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Hmm, so that would make it appear 1 second after the user scrolls past the .selector piece of the page? Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking if that works correctly, I would just hide the DIV initially in CSS, right?

Comment: no, you must put '$("elementtoappear").hide();' first for the element to be initially hidden

Comment: Hmm, alright, thanks for all the help. Is there any way to make it activate at the bottom of a DIV rather than the top of a DIV?

Comment: Not sure what you mean:  do you want the event to trigger if you hit the bottom of the div?  if so see my edit

Comment: Sort of, I was wondering if you can activate the .delay when the bottom (or closing tags of the specified DIV) appears.

So instead of activating the div when the top of another DIV hits the top of your screen, make it so the .delay occurs when the top of your div hits the bottom of the screen.

So pretend like you have a blog post, I'm trying to make it so that once the person has any amount of space showing below the blog post, then the new DIV will appear. Know what I mean?

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what I'm looking for, is there any way to make the height of the div0/tall div change depending on how tall the blog post is, because they vary depending on the amount of content I put into each post, so it changes a lot.

Comment: yea, simply don't set a height in the css styling and the height will adjust to the contents of the div.  i put in a height so the div would be taller than the page

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all blogposts have a class of blogpost. Add to each one the style of `display:none`. Then this is code that will make it happen.

```
$(function(){
    var $blogs = $('.blogpost');

    $(window).scroll(function(){

     var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();

        $blogs.each(function(){
            var elemTop = $(this).offset().top;
            var elemBottom = elemTop + $(this).height();

            if(windowBottom > elemBottom){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(this).show();
                }, 1000);

            }
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks awesome. Thanks a ton, but wouldn't I want something like scrollBottom (if that is a thing)? Because the DIV that I want to appear comes after the post, so the user would scroll to the bottom of the post then after a second the DIV appears?

Comment: @user2059175 there is not function for that. What I have done is worked it out for you and when we check `windowBottom > elemBottom`, we are indeed checking the bottom of the post. If you want more scroll just add some. e.g. `windowBottom > (elemBottom + 100)`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to perform an action (call a function) after a delay, and you can hook the `scroll` event of an element (including the document as a whole) quite easily with jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) function (or its shortcut, [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)). So you might use a combination of those things to make your `div` appear (via jQuery's `show`), e.g.:

```
// At the end of your page, just before the closing </body> tag
(function($) {
    var timer;

    // Set up the timer and scroll event handler
    timer = setTimeout(showDiv, 2000); // 2000 = two seconds
    $(document.body).on('scroll', handleScroll);

    // Show the div, and cancel the scroll event handler or timer
    function showDiv() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(document.body).off('scroll', handleScroll);
    }

    // Handle the scroll event    
    function handleScroll() {
        // Check to see if the body has scrolled up past the top of the article
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#thearticle").offset().top) {
            showDiv();
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Obviously that's just concept, but it should get you going the right way.

Comment: Hmm, that's awesome, thanks! But "Check to see if the body has scrolled up past the top of the article" wouldn't I want it to check it the person has scrolled down past the end of the article, because that's where my DIV I want to appear is?

Comment: @user2059175: That's what that means. :-) Just a difference in terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this worked, from another page on SO.

But I'm wondering if there is a way to make it activate say 200 pixels above the scrollTop function.

Right now it activates when a user scrolls to the absolute start of the first DIV, but I'd rather be able to activate it when a user comes the bottom of a DIV.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
        $("#dvid").show(); //reached the desired point -- show div
    }
});
```

});